# Override vs extend Django's models.Manager to handle deleted objects (best practice)

Tags: django, django-models

There is a requirement, that nothing should be deleted from database (no rows should be deleted)

So, obviously, all models should be inherited from something like this:

```
class BaseModel(models.Model):
    is_deleted = models.BooleanField(default=False)
```

But, it is not obvious how to make `models.Manager` to handle `is_deleted` the best way

**I can imagine two options:**

**1) Override** `BaseModel`'s `Manager`'s `._get_query_set()` **method**

So, both will return only active objects (marked as `is_deleted=False`):

```
Article.objects.all()
Article.objects.filter(id__in=[1, 2])
```

Even `.get(...)` will raise 404 if `is_deleted=True`:

```
Article.objects.get(id=1)
```

Also, extend with additional method, to be able to actually access `is_deleted=True`:

```
Article.objects.deleted(id=1)
```

**2) Second option is to extend** `BaseModel` **with additional second** `Manager`, **let's say -** `actual`

So, all three will exclude objects with `is_deleted=True`:

```
Article.actual.all()
Article.actual.filter(id__in=[1, 2])
Article.actual.get(id=1)  # 404 even if in db, but is_deleted=True
```

At the same time, regular `objects` works and stands with native behaviour (ignore `is_deleted` or not):

```
Article.objects.all()
Article.objects.filter(id__in=[1, 2])
Article.objects.get(id=1)
```

---

Maybe there are another good options? Is there a best practice?

Big thx for advices!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### 1 or 2 options?

From the [django docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/db/managers/#default-managers):

> If you use custom Manager objects, take note that the first Manager Django encounters (in the order in which they’re defined in the model) has a special status. Django interprets the first Manager defined in a class as the “default” Manager, and several parts of Django (including dumpdata) will use that Manager exclusively for that model. As a result, it’s a good idea to be careful in your choice of default manager in order to avoid a situation where overriding get_queryset() results in an inability to retrieve objects you’d like to work with.

Also any third party apps you use, will also likely use the default manager. Ask yourself if it is important for any of these apps to access any of your 'deleted' rows.

For the above reason I think I would probably opt for the two managers option.

#### Another consideration

When you say "nothing should be deleted from database" do you mean that no rows should be deleted, or no data should ever be removed. If the later, remember that when you update a row, that old data is lost forever, and in that sense the data is 'deleted'.

To avoid this you can have a system where you only ever add rows to your database. You would need a non-unique id field to identify which rows you use, and when you get a particular id, you chose the most recently updated row with that id. Just a thought.

Comment: Big thx for an answer (I've updated the question, ye - no rows should be deleted)
Also dumpdata is a great argument